# WPF: Potmeter custom control

Tags: wpf, controls

I'm trying to find out how to make a custom knob control. To explain I have included a mockup[image]:

I would like the numeric values shown to be databindable (and include ticks to optionally snap to) I think I have to take the slider as a base but it's confusing how to make a custom control properly and databind all the values.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just have a look at the guage control for a reference

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/circulargaugecontrol.aspx